# Optimizing SELECT Query on Oracle 10 Dense Unique Index

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have a table in Oracle 10 with following structure

```
Create Table Bookmarks(  
    BOOKMARKID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    URL VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

URL has a unique constraint set thus a unique index. There are about 1 million records in this table. I have to frequently check if a bookmark already exists in the table. I am issuing the following query

```
Select bookmarkid from Bookmarks where URL='<some url>'
```

The problem is that as the number of records have grown so has the performance gone down. Now It takes significantly longer to return the bookmark id specially when the query URL is long. In the Explain Plan the query does use Unique index on URL column. Any suggestions for improving response time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically use a hash index for this. In mssql I would create a persisted computed column that did like CRC(url). Then when you want to check for existance, you look up WHERE crc('some url') = PersistedCrcColumn AND URL='some url'

You have to include the original check with the crc check since you can occassionally get CRC collisions.

EDIT - changing my description above from 'hash lookup' to 'hash index' to avoid confusion. Some dbs have hash indexes as a first class index, I don't believe oracle does (and I know mssql doesn't). If it is not supported intrinsically, the above approach is how you implement it manually.

Answer (score 3):

Make index that includes bookmarkid column also.
Like this:

```
create IX on bookmarks (url, bookmarkid);
```

Comment: I'm voting up Dmitry's answer - in case it is not obvious, including the bookmarkid column in the index eliminates the need for Oracle to visit the table segment blocks to retrieve the information - only the index is accessed.  If the BOOKMARKS table was relatively static then creating it as an IOT (indexed organized table) would be a somewhat similar approach.

Answer (score 2):

Calcuate `MD4` index for your `URL` and assign it in a trigger :

```
:new.HASH := DBMS_CRYPTO.hash(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(:new.url), 1)
```

Create an index on this column and search by the hash value.

Don't forget to `GRANT EXECUTE` on `DBMS_CRYPTO` to the user owning the trigger.

`MD4` is the fastest hashing algorithm, that's why it's widely used in places where cryptographical strength is not important.

Comment: Is a trigger needed? Why not a function based index?

Comment: @tuinstoel: UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw is not deterministic.

Comment: Ahh, it should be deterministic, shouldn't it?

Comment: You can create a wrapper function myhash that wraps dbms_crypto and declare it be deterministic. It is an ugly solution/workaround, the trigger is better.

Comment: I'd go with ORA_HASH
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions107.htm#i1235081
Not sure on the performance of the hashing algorithm, but avoiding the switch between PL/SQL and SQL would probably outweigh that.

Comment: `ORA_HASH` is only 2^32 bits long, collations are very probable.

Comment: REPLACE('collations', 'collisions') in the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the execution plan is using a UNIQUE scan on the index, not a full / fast full / range scan. 
You've probably got a lot of URLS starting with http://www. (and maybe a lot more of the leading values too), which isn't ideal. If you can, go with creating a non unique function based index on ORA_HASH(url) and add that to the queries. It will give a much smaller indexed value with a much better spread of values.
If changing the queries is not possible, try recreating the index with [REVERSE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm#i2075657).

It won't help with the size of the indexed value, but may spread it better.